# JQuery image transition. swipe up

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, transition

I have searched online but am failing to find anyhting that quite matches what I am after. 
I want to have my images changing using a swipe transition. Like can be seen on the Windows 8 preview release video ( http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/release-preview ) in the first few seconds, where the tile image changes to text then to something else. 
Can this be accomplished in JQuery? Or is there a better way?

Thanks.

EDIT: I have found the desired effect here: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/browser.html Under the "scrollUp" option on the left. But I cant for the life of me get it to work on my page!
Could anyone direct me as to where to provided code should go within the following script?

```
<img id="img" src="link here">
<script>
function changeImage()
{
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    img.src = images[x];
    x++;

    if(x >= images.length){
        x = 0;
    } 

    //fadeImg(img, 100, true);
    setTimeout("changeImage()", 3000);
}



var images = new Array(),
x = 0;

images[0] = "link here";
images[1] = "link here";
images[2] = "link here";
setTimeout("changeImage()", 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: take a look at [PhotoSwipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/) where you slide images

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this is not achievable through JQuery alone, JQuery provides the slideUp and slideDown plugins which will achieve similar, but it's not a swipe action.

Comment: I have managed to find the sort of thing im looking for here http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/browser.html Its the "scrollUp" option on the left. But despite following the instructions I really cant get it to work on my page!